# Opengl Triangles Benchmark

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to test how may triangles I can draw on my laptop, so I am doing the following on my system:

OS: Windows 10
CPU: Intel Core i5 5200U
GPU: NVIDIA Geforce 820M

Code:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE); // To make MacOS happy; should not be needed
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context

window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 02 - Red triangle", NULL, NULL);
if( window == NULL ){
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Initialize GLEW
glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    getchar();
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );


// Number of triangles
const int v = 200;
static  GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[v*9] = { 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
     0.8f, 0.f, 0.0f,
     0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

// fill buffer of triangles
for (int i = 9; i < v * 9; i += 9)
{
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i] = g_vertex_buffer_data[0];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+1] = g_vertex_buffer_data[1];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+2] = g_vertex_buffer_data[2];

    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+3] = g_vertex_buffer_data[3];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+4] = g_vertex_buffer_data[4];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+5] = g_vertex_buffer_data[5];

    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+6] = g_vertex_buffer_data[6];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+7] = g_vertex_buffer_data[7];
    g_vertex_buffer_data[i+8] = g_vertex_buffer_data[8];
}

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

int frameNr = 0;
char text[100];
do{

    // Clear the screen
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, v*3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    //glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    frameNr++;
    sprintf_s(text, "%d %d %d", frameNr, clock() / 1000, (frameNr * 1000) / (clock() + 1));
    glfwSetWindowTitle(window, text);

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

// Cleanup VBO
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glDeleteProgram(programID);

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

return 0;
```

What wonders me there is that I only get about 80 fps with v = 200 Triangles.
This would be about 16000 Triangles per second what is pretty bad isnt it?

What am I doing wrong here in the code, or can my graphics card really just handle such a low amount of triangles?

How many triangles can a modern gpu like a 1080ti handle (I heard in theory 11 billion ones -although I  know in reality it's much lower).

Comment: How much faster does it get when you don't do string operations and window title setting each frame?

Comment: Well i use the setting of the windows title to see how fps i get. But i doubt thats the reason, because of if i remove the calculation of the triangles (all functions with gl at start but not glfw) i get about 400fps.

Comment: Then use something else. For example, Fraps, or update the title only once per second. Setting the window title is not for free, so you will screw your measuring results with that.

Comment: Are you being limited by the vsync rate?  Might be worth trying [`glfwSwapInterval(0)`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__context.html) to disable syncing (although 80Hz is a rather odd vsync rate).

Comment: i adjusted the code as u said (every 100 frames i update the title) but the results are still about 80 fps :/

Comment: i compile as c++

Comment: In general: Are those results strange? What results would you generally expect?

Comment: As a minor improvement you could move the `glVertexAttribPointer` and `gl{En,Dis}ableVertexAttribArray` calls out of the loop.

Comment: Did you make sure the NVIDIA GPU is used instead of your Intel GPU?

Comment: @Botje i think so, i used: sprintf_s(text, "%d %d %d %s %s", frameNr, clock() / 1000, (frameNr * 1000) / (clock() + 1), glGetString(GL_VENDOR), glGetString(GL_RENDERER)); And it gave me: NVIDIA Corporation 820M/PCIe/SSE2

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't yet have enough reputation to comment, let me ask here: How large are your triangles? It's hard to tell without having seen the vertex shader, but assuming those coordinates in your code are directly mapped to normalized device coordinates, your triangle covers a significant part of the screen. If I'm not mistaken, you basically draw the same triangle over and over on top of itself. Thus, you will most likely be fillrate limited. To get more meaningful results, you might rather want to just draw a grid of non-overlapping triangles or at least a random triangle soup instead. To further minimize fillrate and framebuffer bandwidth requirements, you might wanna make sure that depth buffering and blending are turned off.

If you're interested in raw triangles per second, why do you enable MSAA? Doing so just artificially amplifies rasterizer load. As others have noted too, V-Sync is likely switched off as 80 Hz would be a rather weird refresh rate, but better make sure and explicitly switch it off via `glfwSwapInterval(0)`. Rather than estimating total frame time like you do, you might want to consider measuring the actual drawing time on the GPU using a [`GL_TIME_ELAPSED` query](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Query_Object#Timer_queries).

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the reason, the shader just writes them on their original coordinate, so the fill rate seems to be the limiting factor.